# What is a correct Amp for your RCD?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

If i am running my panel board with the 60Amps MCB.
Does my RCD needs to be also rated at 60A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nah, it should be OK if the RCD is rated more.  There are 2 different jobs being done here:

- Overcurrent detection (at 60 amp setting) - the MCB does that
- Ground fault/Residual Current detection at any current - the RCD does that

  - The RCD *might* also do overcurrent protection, but if it does, it's redundant.

So yeah, perfectly safe to use an 80 amp RCD. It can certainly handle any *current* a 60A MCB will let through.

Obviously a 30A RCD doesn't have the internal wiring to survive 60A going through it, so that's a no-go.